# How can describe slow connection issues?

Tags: web-applications, performance, customer-relations

I have been working on a website containing 3d maps, virtual 3d tours, etc. All of the content is large like images and video.

The problem is the site performs well under normal speed connections but  it take more time to load if network is busy or the internet connection is slow. How can I describe this to the customer? Yes, we optimize the content where its possible.

Comment: You could say that the website has performance issues wen under load or the user has a slow internet connection.

Comment: Try using analogies like chronic constipation.

Comment: What is wrong with "The site performs well under normal speed connections but it takes more time to load if the network is busy or the internet connection is slow." ?

Comment: Why does the internet speed vary significantly at your location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your website has minimum requirements to run correctly. Detail those requirements in a document and give those to the client. If they deem the requirements to be to much, ask them what features to remove to help the speed issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use client-side timers that alert a "bear with us" message when redirecting to a page takes long (generally 10+ seconds is experienced as "long"). Use ajax to have animations running when retrieving data from the database and on the server-side, if it's possible, write the buffer to the client once a certain piece of content has loaded, for example if you're loading a picture album of 100 images, write every 10 images to the client while the next set loads.